# Image is not getting clear captured by custom camera in android

Tags: java, android, android-camera, surface

I am creating a multi-image capturing feature using custom Camera in my app.But there is a problem with the custom camera. Image captured by custom camera is not getting clear as like default camera(Camera opening with Intent)
Please help me out.I have tried the lot of suggested solutions.

CameraActivity.java

```
public class CameraActivity extends Activity {


 private Camera                      mCamera;
 private SharedPreferences           prefs;             
 private String                      clickedMenuItem;
 Button                              captureButton;
 private LayoutInflater              controlInflater = null;
 private View                        viewControl;
 private CircularImageView           imgview;
 private ArrayList<Bitmap>           bitmapArray = new ArrayList<Bitmap>();;
 private ImageView                   cancleimg;
 private FrameLayout                 imgLayout;
 int                                 RESULT_IMG = 200;
 int                                 NO_IMG = 204;
 FrameLayout                         preview;
 private CameraPreview               mCameraPreview;
 ArrayList<CharSequence>             imgarrayList = new ArrayList<CharSequence>();
 Intent                              intent = new Intent(        );

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.camera_preview);

        clickedMenuItem = Attributes.Another_Item; 
        if(getIntent().hasExtra(Attributes.ClickedMenuItem)){
        clickedMenuItem = getIntent().getExtras().getString(Attributes.ClickedMenuItem); 
        }

        mCamera = getCameraInstance();
        mCameraPreview = new CameraPreview(this, mCamera);
        preview = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.camera_preview);
        preview.addView(mCameraPreview);

        try{
            controlInflater = LayoutInflater.from(getBaseContext());
            viewControl = controlInflater.inflate(R.layout.control, null);
            LayoutParams layoutParamsControl
            = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
            LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT);

            this.addContentView(viewControl, layoutParamsControl);
            }catch(Exception e)
            {e.printStackTrace();}
        captureButton = (Button)viewControl.findViewById(R.id.button_capture);
        Button doneBtn = (Button)viewControl.findViewById(R.id.done);
        imgview = (CircularImageView)viewControl.findViewById(R.id.captureimg);
        cancleimg = (ImageView)viewControl.findViewById(R.id.cancleimg);
        imgLayout = (FrameLayout)viewControl.findViewById(R.id.imglayout);
        imgLayout.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        if (isDIYUSer() && clickedMenuItem != null && !clickedMenuItem.equals(Attributes.Kagazz_Scanner)) {
            captureButton.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.cam);
        }

        cancleBtnClick();

        captureButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                mCamera.takePicture(null, null, mPicture);
            }
        });

        doneBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                setResult(RESULT_IMG,intent);
                bitmapArray = null;
                finish();

            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
         try{
        super.onPause();
        releaseCamera();   
        }catch(Exception e)
        {}// release the camera immediately on pause event
    }

    private void releaseCamera(){
        try{
            if (mCamera != null){
                mCamera.stopPreview(); 
                mCamera.setPreviewCallback(null);// stop the preview
                mCamera.release();  
                preview.removeView(mCameraPreview);
                mCamera = null;
                // release the camera for other applicationsCODE_IMG

            }
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {}
   }
    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {

         imgarrayList.clear();
         intent.putCharSequenceArrayListExtra("List",imgarrayList);
         setResult(RESULT_IMG,intent);
         finish();

    }

    void cancleImg()
    {}

    public void  deleteTempImg(Uri uri)
    {
        try {
         File file = new File(uri.getPath());
         boolean isdeleted = file.delete();
         if(file.exists()){

           boolean deleted = file.getCanonicalFile().delete();

           if(deleted)
           {Log.d("tag", "file deleted.");}

         } 
               if(file.exists()){
                    this.getApplicationContext().deleteFile(file.getName());
               }
         }
        catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        try{    
        if (mCamera == null)
        {
            mCamera = getCameraInstance();
            // three new lines, creating a new CameraPreview, then adding it to the FrameLayout
            mCameraPreview = new CameraPreview(this, mCamera);
            preview = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.camera_preview);
            preview.addView(mCameraPreview);
        }
        }catch(Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }


    /**
     * Helper method to access the camera returns null if it cannot get the
     * camera or does not exist
     *
     * @return
     */
    private Camera getCameraInstance() {
       mCamera = null;
        try {
            mCamera = Camera.open();

          //STEP #1: Get rotation degrees
          //  Camera.CameraInfo info = new Camera.CameraInfo();
          //  Camera.getCameraInfo(Camera.CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_BACK, info);
           // int rotation = this.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getRotation();
           // int degrees = 0;
          //  switch (rotation) {
          //      case Surface.ROTATION_0: degrees = 0; break; //Natural orientation
         //           case Surface.ROTATION_90: degrees = 90; break; //Landscape left
         //           case Surface.ROTATION_180: degrees = 180; break;//Upside down
         //           case Surface.ROTATION_270: degrees = 270; break;//Landscape right
         //       }
         //   int rotate = (info.orientation - degrees + 360) % 360;

            //STEP #2: Set the 'rotation' parameter
            Camera.Parameters params = mCamera.getParameters();
          //  params.setRotation(rotate); 
            /* Set Auto focus */ 

            List<String> focusModes = params.getSupportedFocusModes();
            if (focusModes.contains(Camera.Parameters.FOCUS_MODE_AUTO)) {
                // set the focus mode
                params.setFocusMode(Camera.Parameters.FOCUS_MODE_AUTO);
                // set Camera parameters


            }
            else{
                 if (focusModes.contains(Camera.Parameters.FOCUS_MODE_CONTINUOUS_PICTURE))
                params.setFocusMode(Camera.Parameters.FOCUS_MODE_CONTINUOUS_PICTURE);
            }
            mCamera.setParameters(params);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // cannot get camera or does not exist
        }
        return mCamera;
    }




    private static File getOutputMediaFile() {
        File mediaStorageDir = new File(
                Environment
                        .getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES),
                "MyCameraApp");
        if (!mediaStorageDir.exists()) {
            if (!mediaStorageDir.mkdirs()) {
                Log.d("MyCameraApp", "failed to create directory");
                return null;
            }
        }
        // Create a media file name
        String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss")
                .format(new Date());
        File mediaFile;
        mediaFile = new File(mediaStorageDir.getPath() + File.separator
                + "IMG_" + timeStamp + ".jpg");

        return mediaFile;
    }

    public static Bitmap rotate(Bitmap bitmap, int degree) {
        int w = bitmap.getWidth();
        int h = bitmap.getHeight();

        Matrix mtx = new Matrix();
       //       mtx.postRotate(degree);
        mtx.setRotate(degree);

        return Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap, 0, 0, w, h, mtx, true);
    }
    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
    }
```

}

CameraPreview.java

```
    public class CameraPreview extends SurfaceView implements
     SurfaceHolder.Callback {

    private SurfaceHolder mSurfaceHolder;
    private Camera mCamera;
    private LayoutInflater controlInflater = null;
    // Constructor that obtains context and camera
   @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
   public CameraPreview(Context context, Camera camera) {
    super(context);
    this.mCamera = camera;
    this.mSurfaceHolder = this.getHolder();
    this.mSurfaceHolder.addCallback(this);
    this.mSurfaceHolder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);
}

@Override
public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder) {

     try {       
            @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
            Camera.Parameters parameters = mCamera.getParameters();
            if (this.getResources().getConfiguration().orientation != Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {
                 parameters.set("orientation", "portrait");
                 mCamera.setDisplayOrientation(90);
                 parameters.setRotation(90);
            }
                 else {
                      // This is an undocumented although widely known feature
                      parameters.set("orientation", "landscape");
                      // For Android 2.2 and above
                      mCamera.setDisplayOrientation(0);
                      // Uncomment for Android 2.0 and above
                      parameters.setRotation(0);
            }
            mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(surfaceHolder);
            mCamera.startPreview();

        } catch (IOException e) {
        }


}

@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
@Override
public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder) {
    try{
         surfaceHolder.removeCallback(this);
         mCamera.stopPreview();
         mCamera.release(); 
         mCamera = null;
    }catch(Exception e)
    {
        if(e!=null)
        e.printStackTrace();}

}
@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
@Override
public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder, int format,
                       int width, int height) {
// start preview with new settings
        try {
            mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(surfaceHolder);

            mCamera.startPreview();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // intentionally left blank for a test
        }
}
```

}

Comment: https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-cam2 use this camera lib !